# JavaFX Override Loading images from CSS

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to set how JavaFX loads images from CSS? If I could delegate this to a certain utility class.

In Swing I had an ImageStore utility class which loaded the images needed by all the components. The ImageStore retrieved the image from a given URL and cached it to disk for later retrieval. It also used in memory cache for running application to avoid touching the disk on every retrieval. This way if 100 components wanted the same image, the image was only fetched 1 times, and not 100 times.

I have a dilemma now with using CSS for styling

```
-fx-background-image:url('/images/single-search.png')
```

How to delegate this loading to ImageStore?

How does JavaFX handle loading of images defined in CSS?

If JavaFX CSS does some caching on their own, this will only solve one problem. It will not fetch the same image multiple times. However my ImageStore saves all images to file cache where they are also available the next time the application is started a new.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX uses it's own cache class:

`com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager` contains the `Image getCachedImage(String url)` method that is used by the converter used for the background image css properties. (Note that this class is not part of the public API.) This class does not seem to write the images to files and neither is there a way to replace the way the images are loaded in a clean way (i.e. not using reflection or similar means), but keeps references to the images used in memory...

Of course you could replace the `CssMetaData` object responsible for the background properties in the `List` returned by the `getCssMetaData()` method with a `CssMetaData` object using your own cache, but this would require extending every subclass of `Region` you want to use your cache with and using those classes instead of the standard `Region`s...